# How to plot the number of digits appearing in each index in a column as a function of the index in this column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let say I have this dataframe :

```
 A         B   
 1       1401     
 1       1401     
 1       1501     
 2       1601     
 2       1601     
 3       1901     
 3       2001     
...      ...     
 n
```

I would like to plot the number of digits appearing in each index in column A as a function of the index in column A.
For example the output will be:

```
x = [1, 2, 3, ..., n]
y = [2, 1, 2] (when the same number appears several times (1401 or 1601 for example), we count it only once)
```

And then plot this as an histogram.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate with `nunique`, then `plot.bar`:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].nunique().plot.bar()
```

output:

[image]

With `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(data=df, x='A', y='B', estimator=lambda x: len(set(x)), ci=None)
```

output:

[image]